# Getting textarea content after setting it with innerHtml

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I'm working on something in asp.net that requires allowing the user to change the contents of information within a text area. What happens is that I set the text area contents by getting information within an external .txt, .html, or .rtf file and then set it into the text area using innerHtml.

As for retrieving the data I'm also using innerHtml to do that in the .cs file behind the page. The problem is that when I try doing this, I get back what was previously set even if I had replaced every line of text. For example, if I had originally set "This is the initial text" first then replaced it all with "New text" after, innerHtml will just give me back "This is the initial text".

Is there another way to get the new text or a way to get innerHtml to do what I want?

Edit: Forgot to include code.

On the aspx side of the code, I just have a simple text area, 
`<textarea id="TextArea1" cols="80" rows="10" runat="server"></textarea>`

and on the aspx.cs side,

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ces = new ContentEditorService.ContentEditorService();
        strRtfDir = Server.MapPath("Testfile.rtf");

        string strContents = ces.loadEditorContents(strRtfDir);
        TextArea1.InnerText = strContents;
    }
```

where ces loads a separate .cs file that does the loading and saving of the text.

As for getting the content, I'm using

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strTxtArea = TextArea1.InnerHtml;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(strTxtArea);   
        //ces.saveEditorContents(strContents, strRtfDir);
    }
```

which gets the contents and prints them out in the debug window of Visual Studio for now just to see if I managed to get the changed text.

Comment: show some code, both html and c#

Comment: without seeing any code I will have to assume you are filling the textarea on page load without this loading code being in 

`if(!Page.IsPostBack){    //loading code}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ces = new ContentEditorService.ContentEditorService();
        strRtfDir = Server.MapPath("Testfile.rtf");

        string strContents = ces.loadEditorContents(strRtfDir);
        TextArea1.InnerText = strContents;
    }
```

Because Page_Load will always be excuted even you clicked the Button1.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to have fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to get the value inside the text area

```
var text = $('#yourTextAreaId').html();
```

or

```
var text = $('#yourTextAreaId').val();
```